# How to perform a maven release with the JGitFlow Plugin

Tags: java, maven, automation, release, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I have following setup Project A (Executeble) has Library B as dependency and library B has library C as dependency. C can be a dependency of other executeable projects, too. I want to do a release of A and all three Maven Projects are SNAPSHOT versions.

I try to start a release from cmd with maven jgitflow release-start and get an error message cause of the Snapshot versions in the dependency of A. Now i go to the library B and do the same. This chain can be undefinedly long.

How can i automate(I know releases should not be automated) / shorten the release with no-module projects?

Most of the projects use a common Utillities project. Multi-module projects are no way, because we have a lots of libraries that are used in multiple projects. A CI Server like Jenkins is not wished. I have tried to find a solution for this, but everywhere are only multi-module descriptions. Am i the only one who is having problems, to believe there is no better way of doing this?

**Edit 1**:
[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194676/222692) is the only page i found the problem i have but it is nearly 2 years old and i could not find other people who has this problem.

Comment: If they are a separate projects why do want to release them simultaneously?

Comment: We kind of have a similar issue, although the chain is not that long. We do explicitely seperate release for library project and the project that is dependend on that as in our case library project is changing rarely. I'm sure you also have seen the -DallowSnapshot flag (just in case the Snapshot topic is your issue). Other way would be to either have a script that chains the releasing for you (including changing version of dependencies) or even better use a build server (although this seems to not be an option for you)